# NameNode memory consumption is much larger than expected

Tags: hdfs, namenode

According to some articles,namenode memory consumption would be like:
"Each file or directory or block occupies about 150 bytes in the namenode memory."
I found my cluster have 172,963,375 files and directories, 187,792,367 blocks = 360,755,742 total filesystem object(s). But consume 116 GB after GC,Why?

Comment: To which articles do you refer?

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_nn_memory_config.html
Because we use hadoop version is :CDH5.7.0-2.6.0